# Trying to understand how podcast syncing works in iOS 6

Tags: ios, podcasts.app

I noticed that in iOS6 I can't listen to podcasts in iTunes, but only in the new podcast app.

What is troubling me:

- The play-count, played/unplayed status, or progress, of podcasts I
  listen to via the podcast app don't update in iTunes.
- I have subscribed to several podcasts inside of the podcast app with syncing turned on.
  But I don't see these show up in the iTunes podcast section.

This must be a bug, or Apple has completely separated iTunes podcasts from podcasts on iOS6 devices. If that's the case, I'm not sure what the 'syncing' option in the podcast app settings is for.

### How do I fix this?

---

**Edit for clarification:** I found that the only meta-data value that wasn't syncing was the "Last Played" date, which was caused a smart playlist dependent on that value not to work. *So that may be a bug.* Otherwise, I'm still don't understand why iTunes isn't syncing with the podcasts I subscribe to via the podcast app.

Comment: Also I am pretty sure this does not work in iOS 5 either, the Podcasts app and iTunes are always in a different state, and even after telling iTunes to not sync podcasts, they still show up in iTunes. Looks like its time to start filling bugs to Apple...

Answer (score 3):

Same thing for me, this upgrade has brought nothing but headaches.

You can still open Podcasts in your Music App by doing a search for the podcast name.

Deleting the Podcasts app from your phone and killing the Music apps process (or reboot phone) will bring the Podcasts menu back to the Music app as well, hurrah!

Answer (score 2):

I believe Apple's logic is as follows. If you want to sync your podcasts through iTunes, don't install the Podcasts app. Use the Music app instead. If you want to untether your podcasts and manage them independently on your iOS device, use the Podcasts app.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Thank you so much, the podcast app was making me crazy, very good info to know